# Docker: How to access Docker container that image made from java:8-jdk-alpine

Tags: java, bash, docker, containers

I am trying in Mint 19 Linux system. I made a docker image using the following:-

```
FROM java:8-jdk-alpine

COPY ./target/demo-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/app/

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN sh -c 'touch demo-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I run it as `docker run -p 8080:8080 --name myApp -d mygreet` .Image is running and executing the jar file. But I would like to access the running container. I tried  `docker exec -it --user root myApp /bin/bash` I got an error message as:-

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting
>   container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such
>   file or directory": unknown

I could access most of the docker container by the above command. After accessing I could see all the docker container has Linux like file systems. I am new in docker and I got an expression all docker image might have a similar kind file system. Perhaps it is my assumptions. It should depend on the base image. For the above case base image was java:8-jdk-alpine. It might be different stuffs.

I got couple of questions.

1. How do I access this container?
2. How do I know the base image existing stuff so that I can access it correctly in future?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont think bash it installed there, try /bin/sh instead.

If you run the base image directly you can test before building your own based on it.

```
docker run -it java:8-jdk-alpine /bin/sh
```

seems to work

Comment: Thanks this works. So for java:8-jdk-alpine there is no bash. So my 2 question How do I know the base image existing stuff so that I can access it correctly in future?

Comment: Well normally bash will work, otherwise try sh. Otherwise you need the Dockerfile for the base image.

Comment: Well, how would I know which image has bash or not? Mainly I would like to know the content of the base image before I made one from my own image. How do I know it?

Comment: You have to try it as I did. Just run the base image directly. You can do that before you create your own.

Comment: One last question is all docker image based on some kind of Linux distribution?

Comment: Docker is based on linux namespaces that makes it possible to isolate network, process and/or filesystem for a specific process. But when the process/container execute it is using the same linux kernel as the host the docker daemon is running on. So yes original docker was linux only and the images needed to be based on a linux distribution... But microsoft tries to catch up :)